# How do I get client Id and redirect URI from salesforce without having access to an sfdc org

Tags: rest-api, salesforce1-app, integration, oauth2, connected-apps

I'm trying to understand **OAuth flow** by building a **chrome extension**.

I need access to the user's org and the way to do that authorization is via a connected app.

Well what do you need for a **connected app**? -- client id and redirect uri.

How can you get them without having to create a connected app during runtime (because i cannot create connected app on each and every org)

I know other plugins/extentions do this exact thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the common misconception is that connected app is required for every org.

Connected app can be created in a developer environment and that's sufficient for the other orgs to authorize their Salesforce environment and you can store the necessary tokens.

Workbench , Salesforce CLI and lot of third party apps use same method. They have a org where they have connected app and they maintain the connected app and make sure the org is not expired .

Comment: Oh ok, you mean connected app created on my dev org will act as a host-server type thing that would let me authorize other orgs?

Comment: That's correct @omkar